# Why does my Tkinter Button disappear when i try to change the pady?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to center the Button and set it to the Bottom but when i set the *pady* to 300, the Button disappear. So here my Question: Why does that happen and how do i fix it?

Here my Code:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.minsize(1000, 600)
root.maxsize(1000, 600)
root.config(bg = "#524D4C")


frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, padx=20, pady=20)

rolls = tk.Button(frame, width=20, height=2)
sides = tk.Button(frame, width=20, height=2)


frame.pack(pady=300)
rolls.grid(row=0, column=0)
sides.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of using `minsize` and `maxsize`, why not use `.resizable(False, False)` with `.geometry("1000x600")`? Also `pady=300` puts a padding of 300 pixels above and bellow the frame. As the `root`'s height is 600, there is no space for the frame. Try changing it to `pady=(300, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

> Why does my Tkinter Button disappear when i try to change the pady?

It is because the padding applies to both the top and bottom of the frame. You've forced the window to be 600 pixels tall, and 300*2 is 600, so the widget must shrink down to a height of zero for it to fit.